# Map View to controller not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have following html code:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "HomeController")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "HomeController")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "HomeController")</li> 
...
@RenderBody()
```

The Views are called Index.cshtml, About.cshtml and Contact.cshtml

The Controller class' relevant methods look like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Contact me";

        return View();
    }
```

Now my problem is that nothing happens when I click on my tabs/action links.
I am expecting this: `<li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "HomeController")</li>` to behave like a normal `<a href="...">...</a>`, and take me to the referenced view.  Am I missing out something?

I have tried to sat breakpoints in the Controller class to see if the methods that should return the Views are called, but they are never touched

Comment: Change `HomeController` to just `Home`. (for your links to work, your controller would need to be named `HomeControllerController`)

Comment: I guess you mean changing <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>?

Since removing the "Controller suffix" from the .cs file won't do, since I read that they must end on Controller. I tried changing it to "Home" in the ActionLink, but still not working

Comment: Have you checked out generated html? Could this be a bug in routing settings?

Comment: It works after rebuilding, but for some reasen, when I change it to "Home", my tabs get duplicated, and act weird. Has anyone experienced anything like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC uses a principle known as [Convention over Configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) that in most cases simplify development.

In your particular case, the issue is in the convention for controllers. Whenever MVC finds a "magic string" that should point to a controller, it will append the word 'Controller' and use the result to find a class, inheriting from Controller.

So, for example:

A link like:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "HomeController")</li>
```

is an instruction to MVC to:

Build an hyperlink with "Home" as its text, pointing to the Action 'Index' in a class called 'HomeControllerController' that inherits from Controller.

If you want your link to point to a Class called HomeController, this is the correct link:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
```

This instruction tells MVC to find the 'Index' action in the Class called 'HomeController' that inherits from Controller.

Comment: Good answer. Don't try to fight the convention, once you accept it you'll realize how much better this is than ASPX!